# Current Divider Question

Tags: capacitor, current

[image]

Knowing all the values of resistances, capacitances and the value of the current source is there a way to find out how current is split in the two branches?

Comment: Yes, of course there's a way. Those are *ridiculous* values though.

Comment: Is your 4kA DC? If so that would make it a little easier...

Comment: The values in the question are just random values would have been better if I kept them in symbolic form. I am just interested in the relations. It is a DC current source.

Comment: If there were no capacitors, would you know what to do? Capacitors are open-circuits to DC at steady state.

Comment: Are you a student? Is this related to classwork? I am trying to think of the best way to explain it and knowing where you are coming from would help.

Comment: Looks like a homework question

Comment: I'm a student, mechanical engineering. With no capacitors i know how to solve it. It doesn't seem to work the same with capacitors as well as the current in the branches is constantly changing

Comment: @Orestis That's because you have ENORMOUS HUMONGOUS capacitors so your system takes forever to enter steady state since those capacitors are so large they take forever to fully charge up. What you are seeing is the transient response. It will take on the order of 1000 seconds to reach steady state.

Comment: Yeah I have a problem finding the currents in the transient responce. For my application the capacitors are purposly taking long to charge up.

Comment: Well, then that's solving differential equations.

Comment: Indeed that's the hard part

Comment: You say "application" which implies you intend to build this thing. I'll just say that you probably won't be able to find a supply, caps, or resistors that can handle 4000A. Nor will you find capacitors anywhere remotely near 20F. And if you do find them, stay away from them or you will kill yourself on the 4000A supply.

Comment: Sorry for the absurd values that I showed, as I said before these values are random I am just interested in the equations. I am not going to build it, it's a hypothetical problem that I m trying to solve

Comment: Well, I am way to lazy and pragmatic to try to solve it. I would just run it in a simulator. One thing you can do is calculate the time constants of the parallel combo of cap and resistor. 5k in parallel with 20 F has a time constant of 100,000 seconds. So if you simulate it, you will need to simulate for 1 million seconds or so to get close to steady state.

Comment: @mkeith Won't the series 15 ohm dominate over the 5K parallel resistor?

Comment: @DKNguyen at which point? When the 20F cap is charging up, then yes. The cap will attain a fairly high voltage, but then it will discharge through the 5k very slowly, and eventually the voltage across the 5k will be very small (compared to the other voltages... this circuit has no small voltages or currents, LOL).

Answer (score 0):

With a DC current source, the capacitors have no effect on the current division. The current will divide in accordance with well known circuit laws. These require that the current in each leg be inversely proportional to the resistance of that leg. This is because the voltage across each leg is the same since they are in parallel. Inspection of your circuit shows a resistance of over 5000 ohms in the left leg versus only 17 ohms in the right leg. Thus, be inspection without any calculations, one can state that most of the current will flow in the right leg.

Comment: At least once the capacitors charge up.

Answer (score 0):

If the circuit is AC, then you have to analyze it using Laplace transform or using Phasor. You will find the details in the book "Fundamentals of Electric Circuit by Alexander & Sadiku". There're two chapters related to the application of Laplace and Fourier transform.

And if the circuit is DC, after a short amount of time there would be no current through the capacitor. And if you need to consider the initial condition (just at the moment when the power is supply connected), then there's another chapter related to this in the book named "1st and 2nd order circuit".

The book of Alexander is the best engineering book I've ever read.